# Jquery Knockout subscribe not called first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a `ko.computed` function, and a `subscribe` function:

The subscribe function gets called only after `computed` function has been triggered by the user, and not for the first time also:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StALB/) Demo

Javascript:

```
var viewModel = {
    isChecked: ko.observable(false)
};
viewModel.isValid = ko.computed(function(){
    console.log("calling isValid");
    return this.isChecked();
}, viewModel);
viewModel.isValid.subscribe(function(value) {
    console.log("isValid changed");
});
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked" />
<label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
```

How can i "trigger" the subscribe function on init as well?

Comment: Why are you subscribing to the `computed` instead of the `observable`? By definition a computed is only "changed" when you explicitly call it

Comment: Because `isValid` normally uses more observables, and not just one. I've made it like this for simplicity

Comment: computed and subscriptions only fire when the value is changed not upon initialisation. what are you trying to achieve by firing it on init?

Comment: @Tanner The isValid subscriber updates DOM elements, and i wanted to update them on init. However, i think i will just call the function manually for the first time

Answer (score 1):

You could always leave the `isChecked` observable empty upon initialisation and update it's value after the subscription is declared, like so:

```
var viewModel = {
    isChecked: ko.observable()
};
viewModel.isValid = ko.computed(function(){
    console.log("calling isValid");
    return this.isChecked();
}, viewModel);
viewModel.isValid.subscribe(function(value) {
    console.log("isValid changed");
});

// set default value here to fire subscription code
viewModel.isChecked(false);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StALB/1/).

Not sure if it's an issue, but this will call your computed function too on the init.

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to all your observables instead:

```
var viewModel = {
   isChecked1: ko.observable(false),
   isChecked2: ko.observable(false),
   isChecked3: ko.observable(false)
};
viewModel.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
    return viewModel.isChecked1() && viewModel.isChecked2() && viewModel.isChecked3();
});
viewModel.isChecked1.subscribe(validChange);
viewModel.isChecked2.subscribe(validChange);
viewModel.isChecked3.subscribe(validChange);

function validChange() {
    console.log("isValid Changed to: " + viewModel.isValid());
};
```